# is it possible to load the content of one nmml from another one?

Tags: haxe, nme

Is it possible to have one main project.nmml file with multiple children overriding some of the configuration?

ie

```
project.nmml
project_ouya.nmml
```

And call `nme test "project_ouya.nmml" android`.

Or is there a better solution for this type of scenarios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **project_ouya.nmml**, add `<include name="project.nmml" />`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work... I get `Error : Invalid class name nme_install_tool`

Comment: That should be the bug I've fixed some time ago ( https://github.com/haxenme/NME/commit/7d257ae1b5dddaf5b5279447bd4b56f461ddb163 ). Try to use a more recent version of NME.